# Do something every time a list length increases by a certain amount

Tags: python, list

I want my code to take a break every time one of my list (tumblr or save) reaches 300 entries (ie: 300, 600, 900, etc.)

This is my code:

```
tumblr = []
for half_hour in range(start_ts, until_ts, (60*30)):
    save = []
    try:
        data = client.tagged("fanart", before=half_hour)
            save.append(list([row[4], row[8], row[0], title, desc, url, row[5]]))
            print(row[8], title)
        if (len(tumblr) % 300 == 0) or (len(save) % 300 == 0):
            sauvegarde()
            time.sleep(60)
```

I didn't put the whole script but tumblr gets filled later on in the script so at first the list has zero entry.

The problem I seem to have is that it starts right away with zero. Is there a way to disregard zero in this logic ?

Thanks

Comment: `if tumblr and len(tumblr) % 300 == 0:`

Comment: Check the list is not empty? `if (tumblr and len(tumblr) % 300 == 0) or (save and len(save) % 300 == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing the conditional to add `len(tumblr) != 0`, like this:

```
if (len(tumblr) != 0 and (len(tumblr) % 300 == 0) or (len(save) % 300 == 0)):
    sauvegarde()
    time.sleep(60)
```

I hope this helps.